# How to store multiple images in one session and show that in another page?

Tags: php

I am uploading multiple images and want to display all those images in another page using sessions. How can I achieve this?

**1st Page**

```
$var_holding_img = "<img src='$File_Name' alt='picture' width='200' height='256'><br/>"; 
$string =   $var_holding_img ;
$_SESSION['File_Name'] = $string; //storing multiple images
echo $_SESSION['File_Name'] ;
```

**2nd Page**

```
$File_Name=$_Session['File_Name']; //want to show all images
<?php echo $File_Name ?></div>
```

Comment: help me out with this since i am new in this

Comment: Use an array instead of a string?

Comment: can u plze do it i dont know how to it

Comment: You should start with the php manual.

Comment: can anyone else canhelp me out with this

Answer (score 0):

**first page**

```
<?php
$var_holding_img = "<img src='$File_Name' alt='picture' width='200' height='256'><br/>"; 
$_SESSION['File_Name'][] = $var_holding_img; //storing multiple images
?>
```

**second page**

```
<div>
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION))
{
    foreach ($_SESSION['File_Name'] as $key=>$File_Name)
    {
    echo $File_Name;
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['FileArray']))
unset($_SESSION['FileArray']);

$_SESSION['FileArray'][] = "<img src='http://php.net/images/logo.php' alt='picture' width='200' height='256'><br/>";
$_SESSION['FileArray'][] = "<img src='https://jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery.png' alt='picture' width='200' height='256'><br/>";

if (isset($_SESSION))
{
    foreach ($_SESSION['FileArray'] as $key=>$File_Name)
    {
    echo $File_Name;
    }
}
?>
```